# Python: sorting index column in pivot table by custom order

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, indexing, pivot

as result of dataframe manipulation

```
week_days = {0:'Monday', 1:'Tuesday', 2:'Wednesday', 3:'Thursday', 4:'Friday', 5:'Saturday', 6:'Sunday'}
week_view['day_week_name'] = week_view ['day_week'].apply(lambda x: week_days[x]) 
...
week_view.pivot_table(index = ['paymentType','type'], columns=['day_week_name'], aggfunc={'value':'sum'}, fill_value=0).sort_index(axis = 1, ascending = False)
```

I have result:

[image]

is there way to get it sorted in normal way where 'monday' is the first and 'sunday' is the last column?

i tried to use "key=" argument for .sort_index(), but got error back:

```
TypeError: sort_index() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

**UPDATE** (a kind of solution)
with help of your comments, i find a way to solve the task.
you have to use pd.Categorical to get it sorted. But the problem with pivot table, that zero-rows will be add to final table (that is non if you are not using categorization).
You have to add some more lines to get the result as desired:

```
week_view['day_week_name']  = pd.Categorical(week_view['day_week_name'], ['Понедельник','Вторник','Среда','Четверг','Пятница','Суббота','Воскресенье'])

week_pivot = week_view.pivot_table(index = ['paymentType','type'], columns=['day_week_name'], aggfunc={'value':'sum'}, fill_value=0).sort_index(axis = 1)
week_series = (week_pivot != 0).any(axis=1)
week_pivot.loc[week_series]
```

[image]

Comment: `key` was added in version 1.1.0

Comment: I am running on 3.8.3 (juniper notebook)

Comment: 3.8.3 is a python version not pandas. Your pandas version is less than 1.1.0

Comment: you are right. 1.0.5 ... will update.

Comment: You can try reordering columns and updating in the variable like this -
`new_df = df[['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', ... ]]`
# you may overwrite it to the same variable as earlier.

Comment: @shripalmehta it doesn't work for multiindex, pivot table

Comment: @It_is_Chris - upgrated to 1.3.0 and on key=week_days got: TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: Make a `CategorialDtype`  ordered with the name of the weekdays. That will work also in a pivot. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html

Comment: @HenrikBo Thank you for the idea! It works! week_view['day_week_name']  = pd.Categorical(week_view['day_week_name'], ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']) the only thing bad - pivot add many zero-rows into the table which were not visible before.